# Props are undefined in Functional React Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux pattern and I have a functional component where I need to call in redux actions but my props are always undefined

```
const GetCustomers= (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    //Props is always undefined?
    let test = props.actions.getSomething();   
  });

  return (
    <>Hello</>
);};
GetCustomers.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default GetCustomers;
```

Then I have another js file for mapDisplayToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => state.reducer;
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GetCustomers);
```

I am not sure why props are undefined and does not have any actions.

Comment: if you are using hooks, why not to use the `useSelector` hook?

Comment: 'useEffect(() => {
    let test = props.actions.getSomething();   
  },[props]);' try this so that whenever props changes the useEffect is called again

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372371/how-to-access-props-from-useeffect-hook-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` instead

For selecting a slice of the `state` do this

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

const GetCustomers= (props) => {
yourStateName = useSelector(state => state.yourState)
//OR if you have multiple reducers combined use this
yourStateName = useSelector(state => state.reducerYourStateBelongsTo.yourState)
}
```

For `Dispatching` actions do this

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {yourAction} from '../path'
const GetCustomers= (props) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch(yourAction(args if any pass it here))
}
```

It's considered a best practice to use `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks if you are using functional components